# Electron - Typescript - Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Trying to build my electron app with typescript generated from the electron-quick-start-typescript project. I have added an additional module called auth.ts which is not recognised when I start the app. I am trying to reference it in renderer.ts with

```
import { myfunction } from './auth'
```

[image]

However I can see that it is getting converted into js. What could be causing this issue? Why can't my application see my new module?

[image]

Additionally here is my package.json file if that helps.

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application written with Typescript",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "eslint -c .eslintrc --ext .ts ./src",
    "start": "npm run build && electron ./dist/main.js"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "electron": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. For anyone else having the same issue this resolved the issue -

Make sure nodeIntegration is enabled in main.js

```
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
```

Index.html

replace:

```
<script src="./dist/renderer.js"></script>
```

with:

```
<script>
    require("./dist/renderer.js");
</script>
```